# C# - The CS0136 that shouldn't be

Tags: c#, if-statement, compiler-errors

I have no idea why this line is getting an CS0136 error...

```
if (s => scoresint[0])
```

"s" was already declared as  an integer, but even then, I'm not re-declaring it here, so there should be no issue. Any ideas?

Comment: what business does a lambda expression have in the context of an if condition?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`=>` is the lambda operator, which implicitly declares a new `s`.

You likely want `>=`.

Comment: Gotta love these kinds of questions.  You can actually earn rep on them, without being called a rep whore.

Comment: its `greater than or equal to`. A standard numeric comparison operator.

Comment: @Nix: `>=` is the "greater than or equal to" operator.

Comment: That was an epic brain fart.  I was like really?  There is a different type of lambda...

Comment: Yes, a rookie mistake. Ha-ha. I'm stupid and all that. Regardless, thanks for the right answer :P

Answer (score 3):

As Mr. White points out, you want `>=`. To understand why you're getting the error, `s => scoresint[0]` is declaring an anonymous function whose parameter will be named `s`. Since that name is already used by your local variable, the compiler reports the error you see.